# Order of reading files from folder

Tags: java

Is there a default order of reading and processing a list of files with java of a folder from a windows server or does it depend on the windows sort order of the folder?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not try it yourself and see?

Comment: I noticed that some weeks ago. My workaround was to call `Arrays.sort(files);`, with `files` being `File[]`

Answer (score 0):

It is not specific and you don't need to rely on this order. From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--):

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.